# Why did microsoft not included system.data in silverlight? Is support being dropped?

Tags: silverlight

Is support for system.data namespaces being dropped in near future?

Comment: Duplicate to [my question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885338/why-microsoft-did-not-include-sql-server-support-in-silverlight)

Comment: o but i was shouting, am terrified by the idea that i have to write all my projects again without system.data!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

System.Data is used to access SQL Databases, and isn't particularly relevant to Silverlight. As such, they would have removed those classes to decrease the size of the runtime.

Microsoft are not removing System.Data from the main .NET platform, and it's extremely unlikely they ever would.

Comment: @user287745:  In order to get a more authoritative source to "certify" this answer you would need to ask Microsoft themselves.  No one else can furnish you with such a "certificate".

Comment: I can't give you a more authoritive answer, other than to say I'd bet my life 100% of the fact that Microsoft will never remove System.Data. It's such a core part of the platform.